# googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was trying get the video data from Youtube data API, but I am experiencing (500) Backend Error after certain number of request calls(approx 900), also I have tried to wait for 15 minutes interval for 4 to 5 times still it throws same error

Error:

> b'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "backendError",\n    "message": "Backend Error"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 500,\n  "message": "Backend Error"\n }\n}\n'
>
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&forContentOwner=true&alt=json&type=video&pageToken=xxxxxreturned "Backend Error">

This is the piece if code in python to make a request iteratively:

```
search_data = search_list_mine(youtube_data, part='snippet', maxResults=50,
                                   forContentOwner=True,
                                   onBehalfOfContentOwner='xxxxxxxx', type='video',
                                   pageToken="xxxxxxxx")
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you not a youtube partner let remove these codeforContentOwner=True,
                                   onBehalfOfContentOwner='xxxxxxxx',